# OpenGL GL_TEXTURE1 not displaying

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, textures, glew

I am trying to load two different textures, one in GL_TEXTURE0 and the other in GL_TEXTURE1, when I set the sampler2d using the uniform variable in my fragment shader still only the first texture shows up. Please let me know what is wrong with the following code .

```
// main.cpp
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include <stb/stb_image.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "Shader.hpp"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height);
void processInput(GLFWwindow *window);

// settings
const unsigned int SCR_WIDTH = 800;
const unsigned int SCR_HEIGHT = 600;


int main()
{
    // glfw: initialize and configure
    // ------------------------------
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);


    // glfw window creation
    // --------------------
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "LearnOpenGL", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);

    // glad: load all OpenGL function pointers
    // ---------------------------------------
    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    glfwSwapInterval( 1 ) ; 
    // build and compile our shader zprogram
    // ------------------------------------
    Shader ourShader("shader.vert", "shader.frag"); 

    // set up vertex data (and buffer(s)) and configure vertex attributes
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------
    float vertices[] = {
        // positions          // colors           // texture coords
         0.25f,  0.25f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,   0.8f, 0.8f, // top right
         0.25f, -0.25f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,   0.8f, 0.2f, // bottom right
        -0.25f, -0.25f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,   0.2f, 0.2f, // bottom left
        -0.25f,  0.25f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,   0.2f, 0.8f  // top left 
    };
    unsigned int indices[] = {  
        0, 1, 3, // first triangle
        1, 2, 3  // second triangle
    };
    unsigned int VBO, VAO, EBO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // position attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    // color attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    // texture coord attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(6 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);


    // load and create a texture 
    // -------------------------
    unsigned int texture;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    // /glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE0 ) ;
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture); // all upcoming GL_TEXTURE_2D operations now have effect on this texture object

    // set the texture wrapping parameters
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);    // set texture wrapping to GL_REPEAT (default wrapping method)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    // set texture filtering parameters
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    // load image, create texture and generate mipmaps
    int width, height, nrChannels;
    // The FileSystem::getPath(...) is part of the GitHub repository so we can find files on any IDE/platform; replace it with your own image path.
    std::string picture = "sample.png" ; 
    stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load( 1 ) ; 
    unsigned char *data = stbi_load( picture.c_str(), &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);
    if (data)
    {
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to load texture" << std::endl;
    }
    stbi_image_free(data);

    unsigned int texture2;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture2);
    //glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    glActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE1 ) ;
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture2); // all upcoming GL_TEXTURE_2D operations now have effect on this texture object
    // set the texture wrapping parameters
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);    // set texture wrapping to GL_REPEAT (default wrapping method)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    // set texture filtering parameters
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    // load image, create texture and generate mipmaps
    int width2, height2, nrChannels2;
    // The FileSystem::getPath(...) is part of the GitHub repository so we can find files on any IDE/platform; replace it with your own image path.
    std::string picture2 = "Test.png" ; 
    stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load( 1 ) ; 
    unsigned char *data2 = stbi_load( picture2.c_str(), &width2, &height2, &nrChannels2, 0);
    if (data2)
    {
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, width2, height2, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data2);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to load texture" << std::endl;
    }
    stbi_image_free(data2);

    // render loop
    // -----------
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start, end; 
    GLuint tex1Location = glGetUniformLocation( ourShader.ID , "texture2" ) ; 
    glUniform1i( tex1Location , 0 ) ; 


    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        start = std::chrono::system_clock::now(  ) ; 
        // input
        // -----
        processInput(window);

        // render
        // ------
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // bind Texture
        //glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture2);

        // render container
        ourShader.use();
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

        // glfw: swap buffers and poll IO events (keys pressed/released, mouse moved etc.)
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
        end = std::chrono::system_clock::now(  ) ;
        std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end - start; 
        std::time_t end_time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(end); 
            unsigned int xx = 1 ; 

        if( elapsed_seconds.count(  ) < (float) 1 / 2 )
        {
            while( elapsed_seconds.count(  ) < (float) 1 / 22 )
            {
                glfwPollEvents( ) ;
                if( glfwWindowShouldClose( window ) )
                {
                    break ; 
                }
                end = std::chrono::system_clock::now(  ) ;
                elapsed_seconds = end - start; 
                usleep(1) ;
            }
        }

    }

    // optional: de-allocate all resources once they've outlived their purpose:
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &EBO);

    // glfw: terminate, clearing all previously allocated GLFW resources.
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

// process all input: query GLFW whether relevant keys are pressed/released this frame and react accordingly
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void processInput(GLFWwindow *window)
{
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);
}

// glfw: whenever the window size changed (by OS or user resize) this callback function executes
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    // make sure the viewport matches the new window dimensions; note that width and 
    // height will be significantly larger than specified on retina displays.
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}
```

```
// Sahder.hpp

#ifndef SHADER_H
#define SHADER_H

#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>

#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

class Shader
{
public:
    unsigned int ID;
    // constructor generates the shader on the fly
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Shader(const char* vertexPath, const char* fragmentPath, const char* geometryPath = nullptr)
    {
        // 1. retrieve the vertex/fragment source code from filePath
        std::string vertexCode;
        std::string fragmentCode;
        std::string geometryCode;
        std::ifstream vShaderFile;
        std::ifstream fShaderFile;
        std::ifstream gShaderFile;
        // ensure ifstream objects can throw exceptions:
        vShaderFile.exceptions (std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);
        fShaderFile.exceptions (std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);
        gShaderFile.exceptions (std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);
        try 
        {
            // open files
            vShaderFile.open(vertexPath);
            fShaderFile.open(fragmentPath);
            std::stringstream vShaderStream, fShaderStream;
            // read file's buffer contents into streams
            vShaderStream << vShaderFile.rdbuf();
            fShaderStream << fShaderFile.rdbuf();       
            // close file handlers
            vShaderFile.close();
            fShaderFile.close();
            // convert stream into string
            vertexCode = vShaderStream.str();
            fragmentCode = fShaderStream.str();         
            // if geometry shader path is present, also load a geometry shader
            if(geometryPath != nullptr)
            {
                gShaderFile.open(geometryPath);
                std::stringstream gShaderStream;
                gShaderStream << gShaderFile.rdbuf();
                gShaderFile.close();
                geometryCode = gShaderStream.str();
            }
        }
        catch (std::ifstream::failure e)
        {
            std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FILE_NOT_SUCCESFULLY_READ" << std::endl;
        }
        const char* vShaderCode = vertexCode.c_str();
        const char * fShaderCode = fragmentCode.c_str();
        // 2. compile shaders
        unsigned int vertex, fragment;
        // vertex shader
        vertex = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(vertex, 1, &vShaderCode, NULL);
        glCompileShader(vertex);
        checkCompileErrors(vertex, "VERTEX");
        // fragment Shader
        fragment = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(fragment, 1, &fShaderCode, NULL);
        glCompileShader(fragment);
        checkCompileErrors(fragment, "FRAGMENT");
        // if geometry shader is given, compile geometry shader
        unsigned int geometry;
        if(geometryPath != nullptr)
        {
            const char * gShaderCode = geometryCode.c_str();
            geometry = glCreateShader(GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER);
            glShaderSource(geometry, 1, &gShaderCode, NULL);
            glCompileShader(geometry);
            checkCompileErrors(geometry, "GEOMETRY");
        }
        // shader Program
        ID = glCreateProgram();
        glAttachShader(ID, vertex);
        glAttachShader(ID, fragment);
        if(geometryPath != nullptr)
            glAttachShader(ID, geometry);
        glLinkProgram(ID);
        checkCompileErrors(ID, "PROGRAM");
        // delete the shaders as they're linked into our program now and no longer necessery
        glDeleteShader(vertex);
        glDeleteShader(fragment);
        if(geometryPath != nullptr)
            glDeleteShader(geometry);

    }
    // activate the shader
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void use() 
    { 
        glUseProgram(ID); 
    }
    // utility uniform functions
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void setBool(const std::string &name, bool value) const
    {         
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), (int)value); 
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void setInt(const std::string &name, int value) const
    { 
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), value); 
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void setFloat(const std::string &name, float value) const
    { 
        glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), value); 
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void setVec2(const std::string &name, const glm::vec2 &value) const
    { 
        glUniform2fv(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), 1, &value[0]); 
    }
    void setVec2(const std::string &name, float x, float y) const
    { 
        glUniform2f(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), x, y); 
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void setVec3(const std::string &name, const glm::vec3 &value) const
    { 
        glUniform3fv(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), 1, &value[0]); 
    }
    void setVec3(const std::string &name, float x, float y, float z) const
    { 
        glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), x, y, z); 
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void setVec4(const std::string &name, const glm::vec4 &value) const
    { 
        glUniform4fv(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), 1, &value[0]); 
    }
    void setVec4(const std::string &name, float x, float y, float z, float w) 
    { 
        glUniform4f(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), x, y, z, w); 
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void setMat2(const std::string &name, const glm::mat2 &mat) const
    {
        glUniformMatrix2fv(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), 1, GL_FALSE, &mat[0][0]);
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void setMat3(const std::string &name, const glm::mat3 &mat) const
    {
        glUniformMatrix3fv(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), 1, GL_FALSE, &mat[0][0]);
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void setMat4(const std::string &name, const glm::mat4 &mat) const
    {
        glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), 1, GL_FALSE, &mat[0][0]);
    }

private:
    // utility function for checking shader compilation/linking errors.
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void checkCompileErrors(GLuint shader, std::string type)
    {
        GLint success;
        GLchar infoLog[1024];
        if(type != "PROGRAM")
        {
            glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
            if(!success)
            {
                glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, 1024, NULL, infoLog);
                std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER_COMPILATION_ERROR of type: " << type << "\n" << infoLog << "\n -- --------------------------------------------------- -- " << std::endl;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            glGetProgramiv(shader, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
            if(!success)
            {
                glGetProgramInfoLog(shader, 1024, NULL, infoLog);
                std::cout << "ERROR::PROGRAM_LINKING_ERROR of type: " << type << "\n" << infoLog << "\n -- --------------------------------------------------- -- " << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
};
#endif
```

```
// fragmentShader 
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;
//out vec4 tricolor ; 

in vec3 ourColor;
in vec2 TexCoord;

// texture sampler
uniform sampler2D texture2;

void main()
{
    FragColor = texture( texture2 , TexCoord )  ;   
}
```

```
// vertexShader
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 aColor;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 aTexCoord;

out vec3 ourColor;
out vec2 TexCoord;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0);
    ourColor = aColor;
    TexCoord = vec2(aTexCoord.x, aTexCoord.y);
}
```

any and all help I can get would be beneficial thanks ahead of time.

Comment: Where do you specify you want to draw the second texture? `glUniform1i( tex1Location , 0 ) ;` this binds the sampler to texture unit 0.

Comment: i understand when I change it to glUniform1i( tex1Location , 1 ) ; it don't work.

Comment: @killer `ourShader.use();` before `glUniform1i( tex1Location, 1);`. [`glUniform`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glUniform.xhtml) specifies the value of a uniform variable for the current program object. The current program is installed by [`glUseProgram`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glUseProgram.xhtml).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value which has to be set to the sampler uniform, is the number of the texture unit, where the texture object is bound too. This means *1* for texture unit 1 (`GL_TEXTURE1`).
[`glUniform`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glUniform.xhtml) specifies the value of a uniform variable for the current program object. The current program is installed by [`glUseProgram`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glUseProgram.xhtml).

You've to install the program before the value of the uniform can be set:

```cpp
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture2);
```

```cpp
GLuint tex1Location = glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.ID , "texture2");
```

```cpp
ourShader.use();
glUniform1i(tex1Location, 1);
```

---

Since glsl verison 4.20 it is possible to set the index by a [Binding point](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Binding_points) layout qualifier in shader code:

```c
layout(binding = 1) uniform sampler2D texture2;
```